# How do I get a string to behave as a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a controller I have an array which contains short versions of the months of the year:

```
@months = ['apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec', 'jan', 'feb', 'mar']
```

I then defined variables in the controller:

```
@apr_direct_income = 25300
@may_direct_income = 22100
```

and:

```
@april_partner_income = 1010
@may_partner_income = 2020
```

In the view I have to display all of these fields, and I can do it the long way, but was hoping to DRY it up a little by doing something like this in Haml:

```
- @months.each do |m|
  = "#{m}_direct_by_activation_date"
```

It will output the variables names correctly, but they are coming out as a string. I want it to realise it's a variable name and then go get the value from the controller, so instead of displaying:

```
@apr_direct_income
@may_direct_income
```

It displays:

```
25300
22100
```

I have about ten different types of income to display for each month, so if I can DRY this up in this manner it will turn hundreds of lines of repetitive code into a very small page.

Comment: (Fixed the formatting; you should just indent code etc by 4 spaces.)

Comment: Brilliant, thats been annoying me, thank you!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: While using a string as a variable is common in many languages, it's also not something that is recommended any more. It leads to maintenance nightmares trying to debug "invisible" dynamically defined variables. Dynamically generating methods using `method_missing` in Ruby and Rails is a similar case that leads to confusion, especially in the minds of those just learning Ruby and/or Rails.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the value of an instance variable using `instance_variable_get` like this:

```
- @months.each do |m|
  = instance_variable_get("@#{m}_direct_income")
```

But you should look into using a Hash for this, and store the data in something like this:

```
@data = {
  april: {
    partner_income: 123,
    direct_income: 456
  }, may: {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then do:

```
- @data.each do |month, data|
  Month #{month}
  - data.each do |key, value|
    #{key} = #{value}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
@months.each{|m| =instance_variable_get(:"@#{m}_direct_by_activation_date")
```

But, it would be better to use a Hash:

```
@direct_incomes = {"may" => 25300, "apr" => 22100}

#in view
@months.each do |m| 
   =@direct_incomes[m]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```
@m = ["jan","feb"]
@jan_income = 1000
@feb_income = 500

eval "@"+@m[0]+"_income" #=> 1000

@m.each { |m| puts eval "@"+m+"_income" } => 1000, 500
```

Comment: `eval` is evil. It even sound evil.

Comment: It is not the best answer, but it is not that bad, either.

Comment: @HolgerJust Everything has a purpose for existence (Although not necessary here).

Comment: @sawa: Had this discussion way too often now... tl;dr. Yes, it's good that `eval` is available, but it should be avoided whenever possible. E.g. in this case as you said :)

Comment: TBH I haven't been working with code for long and even I have figured out EVAL is to be avoided where possible.

Comment: @GarethBurrows That is like a proverb, and people believe it without thinking much. The point of that proverb is to avoid injection attacks. But when the relevant string is completely written by the programmer's side, that concern is irrelevant.

Comment: +1 @sawa, but I'd extend it a bit: "...when the relevant string is completely written by the programmer's side..." and there is *NO* chance that strings supplied by the user can get inserted without some sort of cleansing/sanitizing by the code...